# Conflict between Login form and Registeration form in the same page

Tags: php, html

My website has a login form and registration form in one page.

However, the system gets confused and uses both specifically $username and $password for login in and registering when filling up. Wanting to know how to separate and let the system differentiate these inputs. New to developing these

the PHP:

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {

        $user_name = $_POST['user_name1'];
        $password = $_POST['password1'];

        if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($user_name))
        {


            $query = "select * from users where user_name = '$user_name' limit 1";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            if($result)
            {
                if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {

                    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    
                    if($user_data['password'] === $password)
                    {

                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_data['user_id'];
                        header("Location: index.php");
                        die;
                    }
                }
            }
            
          
            echo "wrong username or password!";
            
        }else
        {
            header("Location: login.php");
            echo "wrong username or password!";
        }
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {

        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];
        $l_name = $_POST['l_name'];
        $home_add = $_POST['home_add'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mob_no = $_POST['mob_no'];


        if(!empty($user_name) && !empty($password) && !is_numeric($user_name))
        {

            
            $user_id = random_num(20);
            $query = "insert into users 
(user_id,user_name,password,f_name,l_name,email,home_add,mob_no) 
                     values 
('$user_id','$user_name','$password','$f_name','$l_name','$email','$home_add','$mob_no')";

            mysqli_query($con, $query);

            header("Location: login.php");
            die;
        }else
        {
            echo "Please enter some valid information!";
        }
    }
?>
```

The Login and Registration form:

```
 enter code here<div class="c2">
                <div class="Form C">
                    <div class="form-btn">
                        <span>Login</span>
                        <span>Register</span>
 
                    </div>
                    
                    <form method="post" id="Login">
                        <input type="username" name="user_name1" placeholder="Username" >
                        <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password" >
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    
                     <form method="post" id="Reg" >

                        <input type="username" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" >
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
                        <input type="firstname" name="f_name" placeholder="Firstname">
                        <input type="lastname" name="l_name" placeholder="Lastname">
                        
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="Homeaddress" name="home_add" placeholder="Home Address">
                        <input type="Mobileno" name="mob_no" placeholder="Mobile No.">
                       
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn">Register</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Before you go online please read about `how to prevent sql injection in php`

Comment: [What is SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: "the system gets confused" - then why not use two seperate pages?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 2 problems to solve here:

1. The one you see which is the form submission challenge,
2. The one you're missing which is securing the Login/Registration process

For the first one you can add `name` attribute in your html form:

```
...
<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn">Login</button>
...
<button type="submit" name="register" class="btn">Register</button>
...
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){ 
        if (isset($_POST["login"]) {
            // Login
        } elseif (isset($_POST["register"]) {
            // Register
        } else {
            // throw an error page/message
            die(" >>> 400: Bad Request");
        }
    }
```

And now for the second problem, you need to consider the following:

1. After form submission, validate user input before going through any process and always use parameterized query. This can help with the attack known as **SQL Injection**
2. Secure your form against **CSRF Attack**, google about it first and then you'll find it easy to implement, I suggest [php-csrf](https://github.com/GramThanos/php-csrf)

3. Add `session_regeneration_id()` before `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_data['user_id'];`, google about **Session Hijacking!**

Good Luck!

Comment: What if the user submits the form by hitting enter and not clicking the button?

Comment: @Dale interesting point! I don't know if it's the best practice but I haven't had a problem using this method so far, I think because there are two different HTML forms, when your filling one and hit enter the submit btn of the form you're filling would work.

Comment: DAMN so helpful and I made it work now as I wanted, just getting stated going to be learning more

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate the file of login and registration make another file example is login.php & registration.php and add action to your HTML form action="login.php"

Or you don't want to separate their file make a condition that will identify them if they're login or registration something like this

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
  if(!empty($_POST['username1']) AND !empty($_POST['password1'])  ){
       //login
    }else{
      //registration
    }
 }
```

Or a hidden input so you can identify the login and registration

Note: Learn the how to prevent sql injection